# getting private key from Bitcoin Core wallet

Tags: bitcoincore-gui

I need priv key for my soft, but I faced with such problem:

> Only legacy wallets are supported by this command (code -4)

How to change wallet type (I think root of problem is it) or how to fix this problem at all?